# mongo db write to all nodes with timeout - what will be the response

Tags: mongodb

I'm writing to a 6-node mongo cluster. 
To force write to all nodes, I'm using Write Concern with X=6 and timeout=2000.
My question: what happens if mongo cannot write to all 6 nodes within 2000 millisecs.
Will mongo come back with "operation failed" or "operation partial success".

Answer (score 2):

I believe you mean w=6 and have already read the document about [Write Concern](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/write-concern/). The document of [getLastError](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/getLastError/) explains possible response from `getLastError()`.

The response in your timeout case should be something like [this test case](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/jstests/replsets/get_last_error.js#L53) in MongoDB codebase.

In your case, w=6 with 6 nodes means that if you lose 1 node the writes will all return errors. Is there any particular reason to use 6 nodes in you replica set? If there is only one replica set, 5 nodes could give the same level of availability, i.e. losing less than the majority, 3 out of 5 (or 6), is fine.